# POSTing file as multipart/form-data to a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

RoR noob here...  :)

I need to create a Rails API that clients can call and send an XML file through a POST request.

I've create my route like this:

```
  namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        resource :report
      end
  end
```

and my controller like this:

```
class Api::V1::ReportsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :xml

  def create
    @report_submission = ReportSubmission.create :login => params[:login],
                                                 :status => :success
    respond_with(@report_submission)
  end
end
```

What do I need to do in the controller to receive the XML file that the client will be posting, and then read is content so I can ultimately put it in the database?

How can I test that?

I've created a sandbox project to try this out and got stuck... no idea what to do next. I've pushed it up here:

https://github.com/claudiolassala/api-samples/

Any help will be just awesome!
    end

Answer (score 4):

After doing some more research, I've managed to get that working. I've updated [my repository](https://github.com/claudiolassala/api-samples) on GitHub with the solution.

The main changes were to modify my controller so to read the contents of the file being posted:

```
class Api::V1::ReportsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :xml

  def create

    @report_submission = ReportSubmission.create :login => params[:login],
                                                 :status => :success,
                                                 :results => read_file_data(params[:reportxml])
    respond_with(@report_submission)
  end

  private
    def read_file_data(file)
      xml_contents = ""
      if file.respond_to?(:read)
        xml_contents = file.read
      elsif file.respond_to?(:path)
        xml_contents = File.read(file.path)
      else
        logger.error "Bad file_data: #{file.class.name}: #{file.inspect}"
      end
      xml_contents
    end
end
```

And I've fixed my Cucumber step that performs the post, changing it to this:

```
When /^I send a POST request containing the file$/ do
  @login = "some-login"
  @file_path = "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/features/step_definitions/test_report.xml"

  post "api/v1/report.xml?login=#{@login}",
       :reportxml => Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(@file_path, 'text/xml')
end
```

Please let me know whether there's any better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do absolutely nothing apart from making absolutely 100 % certain that any data that is posted is not harmful :)
RESTfull routes give you a params hash in your controller action in the normal way when posting xml. This is exactly how ActiveResource works
So just interrogate your params as normal.

The only potential gotcha is that Rails expects properly formatted xml for this to work.

The easiest way for you to check what happens is try posting an xml file to your action and have a close look in the log file at the params the controller receives

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base Shows how this works in quite good detail (No you don't have to be posting the xml via an ActiveResource object)

As far as testing is concerned Ryan Bates has a great Railscast on ActiveResource here http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics and here http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource

They are old casts but still totally valid and you can see exactly how to test